# how to add 2 columns with respect of 2 groups?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to find the total utility of person in each each household.SAMPN is household index, PERNO is person index.
there are 2 utility for each person, utility1 and utility2. for each person I want to add utility 1 of that person with utility2 of other persons.

```
     SAMPN     PERNO      utility1    utility2
      1         1           3             4
      1         2           4             5
      1         3           6             8
      2         1           1             2
      2         2           2             3
```

output

```
     SAMPN     PERNO      utility1    utility2    HH-utility
      1         1           3             4      3+5+8=16
      1         2           4             5      4+4+8=16
      1         3           6             8      6+4+5=15
      2         1           1             2      1+3=4
      2         2           2             3      2+2=4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option after grouping by 'SAMPN', is to get the `sum` of 'utility2', subtract from the column 'utility2' to get the sum without the element and add 'utility1' to it

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(SAMPN)  %>%
    mutate(HHutility = sum(utility2) - utility2 + utility1)
# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   SAMPN [2]
#  SAMPN PERNO utility1 utility2 HHutility
#  <int> <int>    <int>    <int>     <int>
#1     1     1        3        4        16
#2     1     2        4        5        16
#3     1     3        6        8        15
#4     2     1        1        2         4
#5     2     2        2        3         4
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
transform(df1, HHutility = utility1 + ave(utility2, SAMPN, FUN = sum) - utility2)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(SAMPN = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), PERNO = c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L), utility1 = c(3L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 2L), utility2 = c(4L, 
5L, 8L, 2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))
```

Comment: smart answer, I was thinking hard about it